# RegExp that match everything except letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write RegExp that match everyting except letters. So far, I've wrote something like this:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/
```

However, during tests, I've found that it works nicely when I write for example: 'qwe' or 'qqqqqweqwe123123' or something similar, BUT when I start String from number for example: '1qweqwe', it doesn't match.

What do I have to do yet to match everything except letters at any position of my input String?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Correct RegExp I found is:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Comment: `/[^a-zA-Z]+/.test('1qweqwe')` yields `true`.

Comment: @Jack This solution didn't work for me. I found correct RegExp like this: /^[^a-zA-Z]*$/

Answer (score 7):

> What do I have to do yet to match everything except letters at any position of my input String?

You need to use regular expression flags to achieve this

try this

```
'1qwe2qwe'.match(new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g))
```

it should return `["1", "2"]`

the `g` flag at end of the regexp tells regexp engine to keep traversing the string after it has found one match. Without `g` flag it just abandons traversal upon finding first match. You can find the reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. I found correct RegExp like this: /^[^a-zA-Z]*$/

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is not anchored, so it will yield `true` for partial matches. If the whole string should not contain letters:

```
if (/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str)) {
    // all characters are not alphabetical
}
```

Or rather, if all characters must be numeric (or empty string):

```
if (/^\d*$/.test(str)) {
    // all characters are digits
}
```